# Tar in a python script give "syntax error"

Tags: python, tar

I'm trying to create a couple of files with a loop, then compressing everything in a tarball.
The problem is that when I add the tar command I get a "Syntax error":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# usual range (0.002390,0.002490)(0.64,0.94)
# plus new range (0.002300,0.002390)(0.64,0.94)

massrange1 = 2390
massrange2 = 2400
thetarange1 = 64
thetarange2 = 94

original = open("defaults.json", "rw+")
text1 = original.read(1597) #first-half, read until character 1601
text2 = original.read(63) #second-part, read from where you stopped for 63 characters
text3 = original.read() #final-part, read from where you stoppet until the end
original.close()

for i in range(massrange1, massrange2):

  mass = str(i)
  print "Creating for mass 0.00" + mass + " and -0.00" + mass

  for j in range(thetarange1, thetarange2):
    num = j/float(100)
    theta = "%.2f" %num

    newpos = open("defaults/defaultsDm0.00"+mass+"Theta"+theta+".json", "w")
    newpos.write(text1) #print first-part on file
    newpos.write("0.00")
    newpos.write(mass) #print mass value
    newpos.write(text2) #print second-part
    newpos.write(theta) #print angle value
    newpos.write(text3) #print final-part
    newpos.close()
    newneg = open("defaults/defaultsDm-0.00"+mass+"Theta"+theta+".json", "w")
    newneg.write(text1) #print first-part on file
    newneg.write("-0.00")
    newneg.write(mass) #print mass value
    newneg.write(text2) #print second-part
    newneg.write(theta) #print angle valu
    newneg.write(text3) #print final-part
    newneg.close()

tar -cvf defaults.tar defaults/
```

When I try to run I get:

```
File "multipledefaults.py", line 43
  tar -cvf defaults.tar defaults/
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But if instead of tar I put "print something" so the whole indentation thing is fine

Comment: That's not valid Python. You cannot put shell commands in Python source and expect it to work.

Comment: You can use `os.popen` to call shell commands however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to have python execute the tar command is like this:

```
import subprocess
cmdline = ['/bin/tar','-cvf','defaults.tar','defaults/']
subprocess.call(cmdline)
```

Specifying cmdline as an array makes it easier to make a part of the command variable.

It is better to specify an exact executable with path like `/bin/tar` instead of `tar` because there can be cases where `tar` isn't on the search path or perhaps has been replaced locally.  This makes sure that the system program `tar` is what is executed.

For more info, see [python subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

If you want this to be platform-independent, you shouldn't use subprocess to call up the tar program because on, say, Windows, there may be no tar program at all.   In that case, use the [tarfile python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix SH commands with Python and expect it to work. They are different, incompatible, languages.

You can use [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) to invoke a shell command from Python, though. Replace:

```
tar -cvf defaults.tar defaults/
```

with:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["tar", "-cvf", "defaults.tar", "defaults/"])
```

Comment: +1 subprocess.check_call() is a better choice if it desirable that the program should abort in a pythonic way, making a big fuss, when the tar command fails.  Since the purpose of the tar command is to make a backup, that might be a good idea. subprocess.call() doesn't abort but will return a code that can be checked.

Comment: @Paul yep, I guess there are very few instances (like fallback discovery of something) where the failure of a command is considered an acceptable outcome :)